# DW01 for Lithium Non-Rechargeable Battery Protection

Tags: batteries, reverse-polarity, bms

I'm thinking of using the [DW01](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf) IC to make a simple non rechargeable battery protection (over current, short circuit, over discharge). The sample schematic requires two Power fets, one to control discharge and the other to control charge.

[image]

My problem is that I don't need the charge control, charging will cause my battery to explode. What I actually want is for the FET to be closed if a charger is present (reverse polarity protection)... is there a way to do this with the DW01 by changing the FET or some other tweak?

Looking forward to seeing what's possible!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement the over charge function yourself. These ICs are tailored to Lithium ion/Lithium polymer cells. There might be a similar IC with user configurable thresholds.

Comment: OK, thanks. Forgive me if I'm oversimplifying, but if I leave out the charge fet completely and don't connect the OC pin on the DW01 will this solve my problem?

Comment: No, mainly due to the lack of reverse polarity protection (look at M1's diode). Also, take into account that the open circuit voltage vs discharge curve of lithium primary cells is very flat, and drop sharply at the end of its life. Your IC might not be able to detect an over discharge condition.